# Run function inside another scope

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope

I'm trying to keep myself from having a very long code block inside an `if` statement, so I'm trying to call another function into the current scope:

```
var f = function(){ alert(a); };

(function(){
    var a = "abc.";
    f(); //undefined
    eval("("+f+")()"); //this works, but eval is evil
})();
```

I'm probably missing something very basic about scopes, or even other (better) ways to approach the whole thing, but I can't figure out whatever it is. Any ideas on how to do this? I don't want to pass in the variables I need through function arguments.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to pass the required variables as parameters you need to make sure the function you are calling is at the same scope (or lower) than where those variables are defined.

So in your case if you bring the `var f = ...` definition inside the immediately-executed function in parentheses it will be in the same scope as variable `a`. I'm not sure how that fits with the `if` statement that you mention but don't include in your code sample, but you can do something like this:

```
(function(){
  var f = function(){ alert(a); };

  // other code here if you have any
  var a;

  if ("your if condition" == "something") {
    a = "abc.";
    f();
  }
})();
```

Or just declare `a` in the same place you declare `f`.

Comment: +1 because that's probably the best way to do it  - put the variable on the scope chain without making it global.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are passing the variable that you want to alert to the function

```
var f = function(a){ alert(a); };

(function(){
    var a = "abc.";
    f(a); //passing it the reference to a
})();
```

---

Edit: Well if you *really* dont want to pass a variable. You need to first set `a` in global scope. When using `var` within a function, you are creating a variable that is local to that function. leave the var out and you are just updating the global version of it.

```
var f = function(){ alert(a); };
var a = ""; // declare a in global scope

(function(){
    a = "abc."; // dont use var, we just update the global scope.
    f(); // F runs and grabs a from global scope
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't say this in the question -  but I don't want to pass it as an argument.

Comment: Updated my answer, but please dont do this, suuuuuch a headache once your code gets bigger.

Comment: @Wes, just FYI- your `var a = "";` is superfluous. You could get rid of it and have the same result. The `a` that you declare first (with the comment about it being in a global scope) references a different object than the `a` that you set a value to later.

Comment: You're right, leaving out var alltogether would just throw it in global scope, but that is super bad practice. Always declare your variables within the scope that they intend to live.

Comment: @evan - declaring *a* isn't superfluous. If *a* isn't declared, then calling *f()* before the line assiging to *a* in the anonymous function has run will throw a reference error. Assigning a value to *a* in the declaration is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

Surprised nobody said this. This is what I would do

```
function sayhi () {
    alert("hi " + this.a);
}

(function () {
    this.a = "foo";
    sayhi.call(this);
}());
```

Comment: This example actually doesn't do anything - `call` and `apply` only set what value the `this` keyword points in a to function. In your example calling `sayhi()` and `sayhi.call(this)` are the same as in both `this` is the global context (`window`).

Comment: `sayhi.call({a: 'foo'});` would work, but at that point, why not just pass arguments?